# Why is Bauddha Darshana considered Nastika in Sanatan Dharma (Hinduism)?

Tags: philosophy, belief, vedas

I found that Bauddha Darshana is considered Nastika. I want to know why it is considered as Nastika in Hindu Dharma (Sanatan Dharma).

Comment: Correct me if I wrong, but I don't think this is a Buddhism question. Nastika and Darshana are not Buddhist concepts.

Comment: For the simple fact that it rejects god entity as well as vedic doctrine

Answer (score 3):

Because Buddha have not accepted Vedas and it's teachings hence Buddha's worshipping is considered as nasthik darshan.

Comment: Hello! Please to try to add some explanation in your answer with citing some sources. One liner answers are not considered as good here. Otherwise it's quite  possible that your answer will get converted into comment.